# Right circular cone

Tags: calculus

> Find the radius and height of a right circular cone with the largest
>   lateral surface area that can be inscribed in a sphere of radius 1.

I know the the formula of the lateral surface area, which is $$πrl$$
but i cannot seem to link the variables together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $2\theta$ be the apex angle of the right cone inscribed in the sphere of radius $1$ then the slant height of the cone can be calculated as follows $$l=2\cos \theta\ \ \ \forall \ \ 0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$$ 
Now, using geometry of right triangle the radius of base of the cone $$r=l\sin\theta=(2\cos \theta)\sin\theta=\sin2\theta$$
Hence, the lateral surface area is given as $$S=\pi rl=\pi(\sin2\theta)(2\cos \theta)=2\pi\cos\theta\sin 2\theta$$
Now, differentiating $S$ w.r.t $\theta$ as follows 
$$\frac{dS}{d\theta}=\frac{d}{d\theta}(2\pi\cos\theta\sin 2\theta)$$
$$=2\pi(\cos\theta\cdot 2\cos2\theta+\sin 2\theta(-\sin \theta))$$

For, maximum & minimum setting $\frac{dS}{d\theta}=0$, we get 
$$2\pi(\cos\theta\cdot 2\cos2\theta+\sin 2\theta(-\sin \theta))=0$$
$$2\cos\theta \cos2\theta-\sin^2\theta\cos\theta=0$$
$$\cos\theta(3\cos^2\theta-2)=0$$
since, $0<\theta<\pi$ hence, we get $$3\cos^2\theta-2=0\implies \cos^2\theta=\frac{2}{3}$$ 
$$\color{blue}{\cos\theta=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}}\ \ \ \ \forall \ \ 0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$$
 $$\color{blue}{\sin\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}}\ \ \ \ \forall \ \ 0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Hence, we get

Radius of the cone
$$\color{red}{r}=\sin2\theta=2\sin \theta\cos\theta=2\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}=\color{red}{\frac{2\sqrt 2}{3}}$$ 
Height of the cone

$$\color{red}{h}=l\cos\theta=(2\cos\theta)\cos\theta=2\cos^2\theta=2\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\right)^2=\color{red}{\frac{4}{3}}$$

Comment: May I know how did you get l = 2cosθ?

Answer (score 0):

If the vertex of the cone is at $(x,y,z) = (0,0,1),$ then the base of the cone will be a circle parallel to the $x-y$ plane, somewhere between $z = \pm 1.$

1. What is the cone's radius as a function of $z$?
2. What is the slant height as a function of $z$?
3. What is the lateral surface area as a function of $z$?
4. Now maximize it using first and second derivative.
5. Finally, use the value of $z$ to calculate the radius and height of the cone.

Can you take it from here?